# Should subscribeOn and observeOn only be invoked by the final subscriber?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java, reactivex

The [Scheduling and Threading](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html) section of *Intro to Rx* says that

> the use of SubscribeOn and ObserveOn should only be invoked by the final subscriber

It also says that in an UI application, the presentation layer, which is normally the final subscriber, should be the one to invoke these methods.

I am wondering if the advice is solid, since I see some situations in which this is not convenient:

1. For starters, I don't believe that the presentation layer should decide where an Observable coming from the data layer should be subscribed. In my opinion, the presentation layer should be unaware if the data is coming from a database, from a REST API, or from memory. For this reason, it's convenient for the data layer to call `subscribeOn()` before returning the Observable, passing the IO Scheduler or the immediate Scheduler as convenient.
2. If the presentation layer gets the Observable from some service or use case (which in turn gets it from the data layer) and this service decides that it needs to process the stream in some computation Scheduler, why should the presentation layer care about this?
3. What about a stream that is originally coming from the UI, so it needs to be subscribed in the UI thread. Then it will be sent to some service to do some work and finally come back to the presentation layer to be observed in the UI thread. That would require the UI stream to be `subscribeOn()` the UI Scheduler, then `observeOn()` some other Scheduler, and finally `observeOn()` the UI Scheduler. In this case, being able to invoke `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()` only in the final subscriber would mean that the stream can only be processed in the UI thread.

Is there some good reason why I should sacrifice the architecture of my application and ignore Rx's ability to easily switch threads by invoking these two methods only by the final subscriber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great to see you have read the book and are taking the time to challenge some of the guidance there.

The reason I give this guidance is because

1. Concurrency is hard, and having a simple rule helps *teams* produce better code
2. Concurrency is hard, and having a single place to locate your concurrency concerns allows for a better mental model of your stack/layering and should simplify testing. The more layers that introduce concurrency in your application, the worse
3. Blocking the UI thread is not good news. Getting off the UI-Thread asap, and then delaying any processing of data back on the UI as late as possible is preferable. This pattern aims to serve that goal.

These are obviously my opinions but I have seen these simple guidelines help clean up code on dozens of projects, reduce code bases, improve test ability, improve predictability and in numerous case massively improve performance.

Sadly, it is difficult to put together case studies of these projects as most of them are protected by NDAs.

I would be keen to see how it works for you or how you apply an alternate pattern.

Comment: Concurrency is hard, however there's more than simplicity to making a good rule. For example, your other advice "Avoid using blocking calls" is supported with examples and I don't have any objections to it outside of testing code. I think that your readers would benefit a lot from a good example of the `subscribeOn` `observeOn` issue. The current example in _DispatcherScheduler_ section is not satisfying because it introduces concurrency through other means.

Comment: Your other points are good, but I am not yet convinced that they outweight the benefits of leveraging Rx's simplification of concurrency. I would prefer making the components that know the nature of their own work decide if they need to switch Executors and to which. Making the presentation layer enforce the non-blocking of the UI thread forces it to also choose a specific Executor, which is knowing too much about how the other components do their job.

Comment: What I'm trying currently is "Call `subscribeOn` before passing a stream if you know the Observable must be subscribed in a specific thread or if you made some computation or IO work. Call `observeOn` on a stream that you received if you are about to make some computation or IO work, or if you are the final subscriber and the Observer needs a specific thread." I still don't have enough experience with this to fully recommend it.

Comment: I understand your last point, and it seems reasonable. If you are working alone or on a small team with a small code base and you can make these decisions, then it could be a good way to go. However generally, I find that in larger code bases, you may not know if the underlying stream will perform any IO or heavy computation. Do to layering and introduction of caching I find that what can initially be a correct assumption, can become incorrect over time. Regardless - issue raised to create and example - https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/issues/26

Comment: w.r.t comment 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675045/should-subscribeon-and-observeon-only-be-invoked-by-the-final-subscriber/34699242?noredirect=1#comment-57305216, ideally you have abstracted your schedulers away behind some provider/service. I have found that in most UI applications we only needed 2 Schedulers exposed `Dispatcher` and `Background` (which delegates to the relevant platform scheduler e.g. `TaskPool` or `ThreadPool`). This provide may also provide a way to get a dedicated `EventLoopScheduler` for specific IO actions

Comment: I decided to accept this answer mainly based on points 1 and 2 of your answer. I was trying the approach described in my comment and it does seem like it would lead to bugs in a big project. Good advice about the Scheduler provider.

Answer (score 3):

1. The presentation layer doesn't care where the observable comes from, per se, but it does care if it might lock up the UI thread. So the presentation layer must take precautions to prevent that from happening. This is a case of blissful ignorance with a layer of safety.
2. The presentation layer doesn't care. It only wants to make sure it itself is not blocked.
3. If the stream comes from the UI **and** it takes a lengthy time to process then the owner of the stream **should** be conscientious of this and make sure that it is processed on a non-UI scheduler. Then the UI has to make sure it comes back to the UI thread if it needs to be consumed there. If the processing is fast then it doesn't matter.

Comment: I agree that the presentation layer doesn't want the UI thread to be locked, but I don't think that it's the job of the presentation layer to decide where other layers will do their work. Besides, this forces the presentation layer to choose which scheduler to use, but it doesn't know the nature of the work (computation, IO, other?). I have a problem with the statement that the presentation should be conscientious of what the other layers do. Also, can you clarify who you call the owner of the stream?

Comment: @sorianiv - I didn't say, "presentation should be conscientious of what the other layers do". I did say that the UI needs to be conscientious of itself creating any long-running observables that run on the UI. The owner of the stream is the coder who wrote the query.